# Hash params for Grape API in rspec acceptance test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

My rails app serves api written in grape. I am using rspec acceptance test to test the apis.

```
params do
  requires :invitation, type: Hash do
    requires :email, type: String, allow_blank: false, desc: "Email"
    requires :first_name, type: String, allow_blank: false, desc: "First Name"
    optional :last_name, type: String, allow_blank: true, desc: "Last Name"
    requires :message, type: String, allow_blank: true, desc: "Message"
  end
end
```

My acceptance spec

```
resource "Invite",acceptance: true do
  route '/v1/invite/send',name: "Invite" do
    parameter :first_name,type: String
    parameter :email,type: String
    post 'send invite' do
       context 'valid params' do
         example_request 'failed' do
           puts response_body
           expect(status).to be(200)
         end
       end
    end
  end
end
```

My output for `rspec spec/acceptance/invite_spec.rb`

`{"error":{"status":400,"message":["Invitation is missing","Email is missing","First name is missing","Primary role is missing","Message is missing"]}}`

How do I define param so the spec passes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was found in `rspec_api_documentation`'s [readme](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation/blob/master/README.md). You can use, `scope` which is a special value for `parameter` to form it as a hash

```
resource "Invite",acceptance: true do
  route '/v1/invite/send',name: "Invite" do
    parameter :first_name,type: String
    parameter :email,type: String, :scope => [:invitation]
    post 'send invite' do
       context 'valid params' do
         example_request 'failed' do
           puts response_body
           expect(status).to be(200)
         end
       end
    end
  end
end
```